# RSACryptoServiceProvider decrypting with ECB and MGF1 padding

Tags: c#, .net, encryption, cryptography, rsacryptoserviceprovider

I'm using **RSACryptoServiceProvider** from **`System.Security.Cryptography`** package. I need to decrypt some input coming from **Android** application using my private key. It's encrypting it in Java code with **`RSA/ECB/OAEPWithSHA256AndMGF1Padding`** algorithm. 
    The problem is I cannot find any way to set nither padding **MGFT1** nor **ECB**.
**Could you help me somehow?** Are these settings default or should I use another library? It's hard to believe it's impossible.

**Crucial part of my code goes here:**

```
RSAParameters RSAParamPrivateKey = DotNetUtilities.ToRSAParameters(privateKey)
RSACryptoServiceProvider csp = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
csp.ImportParameters(RSAParamPrivateKey);

return csp.Decrypt(encryptedAESKey, RSAEncryptionPadding.OaepSHA256);
```

Answer (score 1):

The "ECB" is (hopefully) meaningless.  RSA should only ever be used for a one block of data.

MGF1 is the only standard defined MGF, so it's not an option that .NET lets you currently specify.

OAEP with an algorithm other than SHA-1 is beyond `RSACryptoServiceProvider`'s capabilities.  But `RSACng` can do it:

```
RSAParameters RSAParamPrivateKey = DotNetUtilities.ToRSAParameters(privateKey);
RSA rsa = new RSACng();
rsa.ImportParameters(RSAParamPrivateKey);

return rsa.Decrypt(encryptedAESKey, RSAEncryptionPadding.OaepSHA256);
```